# Reducing i18n verbosity in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, internationalization

Consider this pseudocode class:

```
@interface Dude : NSObject
-(instancetype)initWithString1:(NSString*)string1 string2:(NSString2):string2 string3:(NSString*)string3;
@end
```

And then we create an instance:

```
[[Dude alloc] initWithString1:@"cat" string2:@"dog" string3:@"book"];
```

Ok, so this looks pretty manageable...until we have to add i18n...then it becomes:

```
[[Dude alloc] initWithString1:NSLocalizedString(@"dude.cat", @"Cat meow meow") string2:NSLocalizedString(@"dude.dog", @"Dog woof woof") string3:NSLocalizedString(@"dude.book", @"Book read read")];
```

I'm looking for a strategy to reduce the verbosity of this single line of code.  In most cases we're not passing an i18n string to a parameter, but in cases where we do, it makes reading the code pretty hard.

Comment: You may want to localize INSIDE the method giving the Key instead of the already localized string? You may loose the comment, but I usually put nil in it.

Comment: We create the localization file via: `xcodebuild -exportLocalizations -localizationPath <dirpath> -project <projectname> [[-exportLanguage <targetlanguage>]]`  I'm not sure if this process will work with runtime parameters?

Comment: I meant for example: `[[Dude alloc] initWithKey1:@"dude.cat" key2:@"dude.dog"...];` and in the method `initWithKey1:`... `if (self){_cat = NSLocalizedString(key1, nil)}`

Answer (score 0):

I pass nil as the second argument and keep those strings in my English `Localizable.strings` file.  You could also define a shorter `NSLocalizedString` macro and use that.

If you make your own macro, and use `genstrings`, you need to use the `-s` option to let it know your macro.